# Enveloping algebra of an algebra essentially of finite type (Weibel 9.4.5)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $R$ be an algebra *essentially of finite type* (that is, $R$ is a commutative $k$-algebra and it is a localization of a finitely generated $k$-algebra). In Weibel's book (9.4.5), he says that the enveloping algebra  $R\otimes_{k}R^{\mathrm{op}}$ must be Noetherian. But I don't know how to prove it.

Here is my attempt:

By Hilbert's Basis Theorem, one can easily deduce that for any commutative Noetherian algebra $A$ and commutative affine $k$-algebra $B$, the tensor product algebra $A\otimes_{K}B$ is Noetherian. More precisely, we may assume that $B\cong K[x_{1},...,x_{n}]/(f_{1},...,f_{m})$ for some positive integer $n$ and an ideal $(f_{1},...,f_{m})$ of the polynomial algebra $K[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$, then $A\otimes_{K}B\cong A\otimes_{K} K[x_{1},...,x_{n}]/(f_{1},...,f_{m})\cong A[x_{1},...,x_{n}]/(f_{1},...,f_{m})$. Then the result follows. In particular, $A\otimes_{K}B$ is Noetherian when both $A$ and $B$ are affine and hence the enveloping algebra of $R$ is Noetherian when $R$ is affine.

But I have no idea in the case when $R$ is essentially of finite type. Can you give me any hint for how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can just write $R \otimes_k R$, because $R$ is commutative. Being essentially of finite type is stable under base change, thus $R \otimes_k R$ is essentially of finite type over $R$. Because $R$ is Noetherian, any $R$ algebra essentially of finite type is Noetherian. Thus $R \otimes_k R$ is Noetherian.

**Edit:** Here's a proof that essentially of finite type is stable under base change. So let $R$ be a ring and $A$ and $B$ algebras over $R$ such that $A$ is essentially of finite type. Thus we can write $A\cong S^{-1}A'$ for some multiplicatively closed subset $S$ and some finite type $R$-algebra $A'$. Then we get $$A \otimes_R B \cong S^{-1}A'\otimes_R B = S^{-1}A' \otimes_{A'} (A' \otimes_R B)$$ Now $A' \otimes_R B$ is of finite type over $B$, because being of finite type is stable under base change*. but if we let $T$ be the image of $S$ in $A' \otimes_R B$, then we get $$S^{-1}A' \otimes_{A'} (A' \otimes_R B)\cong T^{-1} (A' \otimes_R B)$$Thus $A\otimes_R B$ is essentially of finite type over $B$.

*If you're wondering why being of finite type is stable under base change, here's an argument: let $A$ be a $R$ algebra of finite type and $B$ any $R$-algebra. Then we have a surjective homomorphism $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \twoheadrightarrow A$ for some $n$. Tensoring this with $B$, we obtain a surjective homomorphism $B[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \twoheadrightarrow A\otimes_R B$, showing that $A\otimes_R B$ is of finite type over $B$.